# Workaround for GoogleAccountCredential.RequestHandler using deprecated methods

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

I'm adding Google Drive support to my app, using the v3 REST Api as described here:  https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android

The exact same problem occurs in Gmail API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android

I'm using GoogleAccountCredential as described there. It gets included via my gradle:

```
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

However, there is a problem with it's nested class GoogleAccountCredential.RequestHandler
In method handleResponse this calls GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken(context, token); which is marked deprecated because it requires permissions MANAGE_ACCOUNTS and USE_CREDENTIALS as stated here: 
[GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#invalidateToken(android.content.Context,java.lang.String))

This shows up when I use the Google web interface to disconnect the app from Drive and try to re-authenticate using the above Quickstart example. This then throws a java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid  lacks any of android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS,android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
(as expected).

I could of course add these permissions to my app, but I'd rather not. The Android Studio SDK manager shows no newer updates for the related libraries.

Any work around except not using PlayServices and instead directly using GoogleAuthUtil ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimenting, I was able to work around this by subclassing GoogleAccountCredential and in it's "public void initialize(HttpRequest request)" use a RequestHandler that's a copy of the default implementation except that it calls clearToken in stead of invalidateToken. clearToken may throw some exceptions that have to be caught and handled appropriately.

Comment: i had the exact same problem with gmail api, and solved the same way you did. Could you accept your own answer? maybe it can help someone in the far future, as it did in the near one